# Python import from own module

Tags: python

I have a module 'hydro' with the structure:

```
hydro/
    __init__.py
    read.py
    write.py
    hydro_main.py
```

This gets used as a submodule for several other modules, which have scripts with similar names:

```
scenarios/
    __init__.py
    read.py
    write.py
    scenarios_main.py
    hydro/
        __init__.py
        read.py
        write.py
        hydro_main.py
```

In order to keep the script names straight, I want to specify the module name on import. So in the header of hydro_main.py, I'd have:

```
import hydro.read
```

and in scenarios_main.py, I'd have:

```
import hydro.read as read_hydro
import scenarios.read as read_scenarios
```

The problem is that when I attempt to run hydro_main.py from the package root, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hydro'
```

How can I set the package name for 'hydro' such that it will allow me to refer to the package name on import? I thought adding `__init__.py` was supposed to initialize the package, but `__package__` still comes back as `None`.

Comment: Try using relative imports, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can import just the entire module as one instance.

```
import hydro
from hydro import read as read_hydro, hydro_main as main

hydro.hydro_main()
main() # same as above

hydro.read()
read_hydro() #same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a sub module so you have to use parentModule.subModule.* . Your first line will change to **import scenarios.hydro.read as read_hydro**

### scenarios/hydro/hydro_main.py

```
print("I am in hydro_main")
```

### scenarios/hydro/read.py

```
print("I am in hydro read")
```

### scenarios/hydro/write.py

```
print("I am in hydro write")
```

### scenarios/read.py

```
print("I am in scenarios read")
```

### scenarios/write.py

```
print("I am in scenarios write")
```

### scenarios/scenarios_main.py

```
import scenarios.hydro.read as read_hydro
import scenarios.read as read_scenarios
```

---

I am in hydro read

I am in scenarios read